# Is 2^2^n = O(2^n)?

Tags: math, big-o

```
 22n = O(2n)?
```

I don't think it is but I just can't figure it out how to prove it

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is 2^n? Isn't it just O(1)?

Comment: Indeed, if all you do is make the calculation it takes no real time (on modern processors).

Comment: @xerx593 2^2^n = 2^(2^n), not (2^2)^n = 2^(2*n). Power operator is right-to-left associative

Comment: O(2^n) is an absolute insane complexity. O(n^2) is bad enough. What is the complexity of 2^n? I don't see why it should get larger as n increases, especially if you're considering ints, it is just a bit shift. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Oh, sry wrong precedence! ...but still and even more than `2^n`.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not

```
Proof: 

    Let x = 2^n, then we are asking if 2^x = O(x) 
    If this were the case there would exist a constant c such that 2^x <= cx for all x 
            => log(2^x) <= log(cx) 
            => x <= log(c) + log(x)
            => x - log(x) <= log(c) 

    This is a contradiction since x - log(x) is an increasing function and will eventually pass the constant c as x tends to infinity
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

---

**Explanation:** If we look only at the exponents of both functions, then 2<sup>n</sup> (let's call 2<sup>n</sup> as *f*) grows faster than n (let's call n as *g*). You can have a look at the chart below.

[image]

So if a number has *f* in the exponent then it will surely grow faster than a number that has *g* in the exponent.

Thus, 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> is ω(2<sup>n</sup>), not O(2<sup>n</sup>), meaning that 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> is lower bound by 2<sup>n</sup>, not upper bound.

Comment: Big O notation refers to the computational complexity of a calculation, plotting the value of a function doesn't do anything to represent the computation complexity.

Comment: You've haven't related that to the computational complexity though. Of course 2^n grows faster than n. I don't see how you've related that to Big O though. I suppose you're trying to do a 'proof' like the answer above?

Comment: @matt: Proofs are overrated. Experience is the truth. :D

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize how math oriented this question is. Can you maybe say what omega is in an edit so I can remove your downvote?